# Advanced group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with 5 columns:

```
property1
property2
property3
rank
date
```

For a given tuple of properties, I get an array of records, which vary in `rank` and `date`. For example:

```
p1value_1, p2value_1, p3value_1 100, 2013-01-12
p1value_1, p2value_1, p3value_1 200, 2013-02-12
p1value_1, p2value_1, p3value_1, 75, 2013-03-12
```

For some *next* available set of properties, I get something different. For example:

```
p1value_1, p2value_1, p3value_2  30, 2013-01-12
p1value_1, p2value_1, p3value_2  15, 2013-02-12
p1value_1, p2value_1, p3value_2, 80, 2013-03-12
```

(notice a change from `p3value_1` to `p3value_2`).

I need to figure out whether the change in rank between the start and end dates was positive or negative. A change is considered positive ("moved up") if the rank has lowered (i.e. the lower rank, the better). For an example above the change is calculated as such:

```
-(75-100) =  25 > 0  --  "moved up"
-(80-30)  = -50 < 0  --  "moved down"
```

The task is to **calculate amount of all positive as well as all negative changes, for each available configuration (set) of properties**.

Ideally, a final return result would look like this:

```
moved up | moved down
---------------------
      13 |         28
```

I figured I probably need to do the following steps:

1. turn all the records I'm interested into small groups (sets) like shown in example above,
2. sort each small group by date, pick first and last item as `first` and `last`,
3. decide what kind of change was that (moved up or down) by calculating

   ```
   -(last-first)
   ```

   – that'd be the *value* of a given small group,
4. count amount of "moved up" groups, as well as "moved down" groups and return the answer.

Any guidance, links or directions are appreciated. If something needs clarification, please just tell me and I'll do my best to clarify it.

**Update**. I'm using postgresql.

Comment: It sounds like a reasonable strategy. What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Floris, I barely know SQL :(

Comment: What database are you using? You have multiples tagged.

Comment: @gmile - well you didn't pick the easiest problem to cut your baby teeth! Perhaps you can show the progress you made - what queries do you have so far?

Comment: @Floris I'm coming from a high level programming language, where solution to the task seems to take way too much time. Thus, I don't have any SQL to show off :(

Comment: @GoatCO I'm using postgres. Sorry, mysql was added only to bring more attention to the question.

Comment: @Floris this is the best I've came up with based on GoatCO's proposal: sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dc5ee/24

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax might be off a bit, but in postgresql you can use the `FIRST_VALUE()` and `LAST_VALUE()` functions, something like this:

```
SELECT  property1
       ,property2
       ,property3
       ,last_value(rank) over(partition by property1,property2,property3 order by date)
        - first_value(rank) over(partition by property1,property2,property3 order by date) AS Rank_Change
FROM YourTable
```

That would return the Rank_Change on every row, then you'd need to group those down to 1 per row and use a conditional `SUM()`:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Rank_Change < 0 THEN Rank_Change END) AS Total_Rank_Down
```

Update:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Rank_Change < 0 THEN Rank_Change END) AS Total_Down
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Rank_Change > 0 THEN Rank_Change END) AS Total_Up
FROM (
      SELECT search_engine,
             domain,
             location,
             MAX(Rank_Change) AS Rank_Change
      FROM (SELECT
             search_engine,
             domain,
             location,
             first_value(rank) over(partition BY search_engine, domain, location ORDER BY date DESC) -
             first_value(rank) over(partition BY search_engine, domain, location ORDER BY date) AS Rank_Change
            FROM ranks
            )AS Sub
      GROUP BY search_engine,
               domain,
               location
     )as SubSub
```

Last_Value actually is quirky, so you need to use first_value for both and change the `ORDER BY` to `DESC` for one of them.

Demo:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dc5ee/41/2)

Comment: This is the best I've done so far as per your suggestion, thanks a lot! Any ideas how do I group those values down to one per row, before actually moving on with counting? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dc5ee/24

Comment: @gmile See updated answer, normally I'd use CTE's instead of nested subqueries, but I don't know much about postgresql.  I suggest running from the inside query out to see the output of each step.  Fiddle query formatting didn't stick for some reason, but the query is there, just ugly.

Comment: I had to alter your solution a little bit to meet my needs, but thanks for showing this code excerpt. This has been very useful!